# Sequentially executing promises inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am straggling with chaining two promises inside a loop, so that promise number two, does not start until promise one has been resolved.

I saw an example with reduce. Could not get it to work, yet. If I just do then, as I currently have, the code executes in parallel - as in, all async requests are fired off, and of course the results are messed-up. Please take a look:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < dummyData.accounts.length; i++) {
  var cursorUser = dummyData.accounts[i];
  var auth0User = {
    email: cursorUser.email,
    password: 'abc123',
    connection: 'Username-Password-Authentication'
  };
  createUser(api, auth0User)
    .then(function (auth0Info) {
      return auth0Info;
    })
    .then(function(auth0Info) {
      cursorUser.authProfile = auth0Info;
      console.log("account: ", cursorUser);
      return create(accountsAPIService, cursorUser);
    })
}
```

Comment: See the [all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method.

Comment: What version of node is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [@Tomalak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34615653/1225328) for the actual solution.

---

The problem is that a `for` clause does not create a new scope for the variables. In other words, you code is understood as:

```js
var i, cursorUser, auth0User;
for (i = 0; i < dummyData.accounts.length; i++) {
  cursorUser = dummyData.accounts[i];
  auth0User = {
    // ...
  };
  // ...
}
```

When the async promise is resolved, another iteration probably has already overwritten the `cursorUser` variable: the `then` callback cannot read the value of the iteration that started its promise anymore.

Comment: This is technically correct but unfortunately not very elegant. There's no need to put up with `for` loops in asynchronous contexts.

Comment: @Tomalak You're absolutely right, code review FTW :)

Comment: I was hesitant of paraphrasing your answer in mine, so I didn't. Good compromise.

Answer (score 4):

Simply avoid `for` loops for asynchronous work.

Arrays have functional methods like `forEach` and `map` for this kind of thing.

```
var pendingResults = dummyData.accounts.map(function (account) {
    return createUser(api, {
        email: account.email,
        password: 'abc123',
        connection: 'Username-Password-Authentication'
    }).then(function (authInfo) {
        console.log("account: ", authInfo);
        return create(accountsAPIService, authInfo);
    });
});

Promise.all(pendingResults).then(function (results) {
    // everything is done
});
```