# How to use promise when variable populated from for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I have a function that makes several async calls which populate the same object with the returned data. I need to do something with the data once the objet is fully populated, and since there are multiple calls, this is not a basic callback/promise scenario.

Is it possible to create a promise in such case? Simplified code:

```
price_options = [] // when this is populated from all the async calls, I need to do stuff with it
sheet_columns = [3,5,7,89]

useServiceAccountAuth(credentials, function(error){ //google docs api

  for (var i = 0; i < sheet_columns.length; i++) {
    var params = {column_number: sheet_cols[i]}

    do_async_call(params, function (e, data) {
      data.forEach( function(item) {
        price_options.push(item)
      })
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: which promise library are you using?

Comment: @Bergi Can you elaborate? I am using Q, only because I have some experience with it

Comment: @ilyo: It's the same as `Q.all`. Get an array of promises, then wait for them.

Comment: Just replace Promise with Q, most promise libraries, and the native js Promise, share similar method names. Lookup [Q.all](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/#combination) in the documentation to see its syntax

Comment: Be careful with `for` loops and async: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34615512/1225328

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers have so much misinformation to them.

What you should be doing is using `Promise.all()` to aggregate all of the Promises. `Promise.all()` takes an array of Promises, and returns a single Promise which resolves when all of the promises in the array have been resolved.

So now, you need to create a function that takes each `params` entry, and creates a Promise for data on it, and push it into a new array.

Since we're using Promises, let's get rid of all the other callbacks you have in your code:

```
// The "functionNameAsync" convention indicates that the function returns Promises.
// This convention was coined by Bluebird's promisifying functions.

// Takes credentials
// Returns a promise that rejects on error, or resolves with nothing on no error.
const useServiceAccountAuthAsync = credentials => 
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    useServiceAccountAuth(credentials, err => err ? reject(err) : resolve()));

const doCallAsync = params => 
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    do_async_call(params, (err, data) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(data)));

/* If you opt to use Bluebird, everything above this line can be replaced with:
const useServiceAccountAuthAsync = Promise.promisify(useServiceAcountAuth);
const doCallAsync = Promise.promisify(do_async_call);

it would even be faster than my version above. */

// Now time for the actual data flow:

const sheet_columns = [3,5,7,89]

useServiceAccountAsync()
  .then(() => {
     const arrayOfAsyncCallPromises = sheet_columns
    .map(columnNumber => ({column_number: sheet_cols[columnNumber]}))
    .map(doCallAsync);
  //.map(param => doCallAsync(param)) equivalent to above

     return Promise.all(arrayOfAsyncCallPromises);
  })
  .then(price_options => {
    // use here
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // handle errors here
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create array of promises.
here is where you can learn more about it.

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
let results = sheet_columns.map(c => ({column_number: c}))
    .map(params => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    do_async_call(params, (e, data) => {
        if(e) {
            reject(e);
        } else {
            resolve(data);
        }
    })
}))

Promise.all(results).then(arr => Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arr)).then(price_options => doSomething(price_options))
```

[Working jsbin here](http://jsbin.com/papefologe/edit?js,console,output)

Answer (score -1):

As other fellows have stated the use of Promise.all, I have written this snippet for you with Promise.all, have a look.

```
price_options = [];
sheet_columns = [3,5,7,89];
var promises = [];

useServiceAccountAuth(credentials, function(error){ //google docs api

  for (var i = 0; i < sheet_columns.length; i++) {
    var params = {column_number: sheet_cols[i]}

    // create a new promise and push it to promises array
    promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     do_async_call(params, function (e, data) {
       resolve(data);
     });
    }));
  }

  // now use Promise.all
  Promise.all(promises).then(function (args) {
    args.forEach(function (data, i) {
       data.forEach(function(item) {
        price_options.push(item)
       });
    });
    // here do your stuff which you want to do with price_options
  });
})
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use promise, wrap your do_async_call function in a promise returning function.

```
price_options = [];
sheet_columns = [3,5,7,89]

useServiceAccountAuth(credentials, function(error){ //google docs api

    var promise_array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < sheet_columns.length; i++){
        var params = {column_number: sheet_cols[i]}
        var promise = do_async_promise(params);
        promise_array.push(promise);
    }
    Q.all(promise_array).then(function(){

    //do your operation with price_options here;
  });

})

function do_async_promise(params){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    do_async_call(params, function (e, data) {
      data.forEach( function(item) {
        price_options.push(item);
      });
       deferred.resolve();
    })
    return deferred.promise;
}
```